# Ubiquity /etc/fstab configuration

Tags: 18.04, fstab, ubiquity

I am building a customized Ubuntu 18.04, using PinguyBuilder, and the resulting iso is successfully installed on target machine.

However, the installation results create common `/etc/fstab` content something like following

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

My Question is, how to change Ubiquity, or any of its components to change the fstab content? is there any template or something?

What I'm trying to achieve is to set the `<pass>` option to `0` to all of my drive.

I can edit the `fstab` after installation, but prefer to set it by ubiquity during installation process.

Thank you.

Comment: just for clarification.. you are looking to get it with pinguy builder only or any other app that achieves what you are looking for??

Comment: PinguyBuilder is preferred. But any other information is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: lee i am trying to understand the concept and would like to try it with cubic.. but as i see my installation i dont have `proc` line.. and what is the importance of mentioning    `pass option to 0 to all of my drive`  according to manpage of fstab `The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1` are you trying to change this value to 0

Comment: Yes, i read about the "should" part of the documentation, and yes, i am trying to avoid any disk check, just to cut the time needed for boot process.

Comment: 0h k.. its clear.. but last clarification plz.. have you ever changed / partitions pass no to 0 and successfully rebooted?

Comment: And this....is "not yet". Need to test it out. But still, need a way to change this, because i will have several drives. If the root needs the value to be 1, it will be fine, i will only change value for other drive.

Answer (score 2):

i find that directly edit `/lib/partman/finish.d/40fstab_hd_entries` can accomplished what I want.

but if any other more elegent way to do this, please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Nice.. You got the solution..